# Finding elements of a list in an array in Python (Numpy, Pytorch)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch

I am dealing with the following problem: I have a list, let's say `a=[1, 2, 3]` and an array `b=[[2, 4, 6],[3, 2, 5],[4, 1, 3]]`, the number of elements in the list is equal to the number of rows in the array, the output should be a list `c=[-1, 1, 2]`, where `-1` indicates that the number `a[0]` was not found in the 0-th row of the array `b`, the other numbers tells the index where the element `a[i]` is in the row `b[i, :]`, the index enumeration starts at 0.

I solved it using loops but I am searching for a more optimal way to do it using `np.where` or the torch alternative, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Is there at most one match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming at most one match per row, you could use:

```
out = np.full_like(a, -1)
idx, vals = np.where(b == a[:,None])
out[idx] = vals
```

Output: `array([-1,  1,  2])`

Reproducible input:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([[2, 4, 6],[3, 2, 5],[4, 1, 3]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
import numpy as np

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = np.array([[2, 4, 6], [3, 2, 5], [4, 1, 3]])

# Create a boolean mask by comparing each element of b with the corresponding element of a
mask = b == np.array(a)[:, np.newaxis]

# Find the index of the first occurrence of True along each row of the mask
indices = np.argmax(mask, axis=1)

# Use np.where to conditionally assign the indices where matches were found and -1 where no matches occurred
c = np.where(np.any(mask, axis=1), indices, -1).tolist()

print(c)
```

Or

```
import numpy as np

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = np.array([[2, 4, 6], [3, 2, 5], [4, 1, 3]])

c = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    # Find the indices where the i-th element of a matches the elements in the i-th row of b
    indices = np.where(b[i, :] == a[i])[0]
    if len(indices) > 0:
        # If indices are found, append the first index to the list c
        c.append(indices[0])
    else:
        # If no indices are found, append -1 to the list c
        c.append(-1)

print(c)
```

#### Output

```
[-1, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much!, your code worked perfectly but I had to mark the other answer as solution due to time reasons, I appreciate your help

Comment: This is a more stable implementation allowing multiple matches.

Comment: @vendrick17 While it's certainly your choice, I would recommend not basing acceptances on which answer came first (the "[Fastest Gun in the West](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/902710)"), but rather which (a) explains it better/has better details, (b) works better, etc.  Acceptances are a 'reward' to the poster, but also an indication (upvotes are the other) to *future* readers of the information.  If a better answer comes along in a year or so, you can even change the acceptance then!

Comment: You are right, thanks for your comment, I will consider it in the future.